# Working with Spotify API - How to follow multiple redirect links in Java?

Tags: java, api, redirect, spotify

I'm doing a Hyperskill project which uses Spotify Web Api. I'm using a Spotify Api Wrapper library (https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java). I'm working with Authorization Code Flow (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow). This means that when the user grants access, Spotify redirects me to localhost with the access token.
Long story short, I am able to create a localhost server with ServerSocket and I can make the user to grant or deny access to Spotify and it's perfectly generates me the access token in the localhost link. 
My problem is that I can't get this access token/code from the callback link (https://example.com/callback?code=NApCCg..BkWtQ&state=profile%2Factivity). I know that I have to follow redirecting, and my guess is that Spotify makes more than 1 redirecting because my code outputs this:

> https://accounts.spotify.com/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.spotify.com%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%123EXAMPLECODE%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%26response_type%3Dcode

```
 URL url = new URL("https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=123EXAMPLECODE&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080&response_type=code");
 HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 ucon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
 URL secondURL = new URL(ucon.getHeaderField("Location"));
 URLConnection conn = secondURL.openConnection();
 System.out.println(secondURL);
```

You can see that it redirects me from "authorize" to "login" and THEN back to localhost and I am able to follow the redirecting to login. How can I make it following to localhost? Or is there any way to get this code from the callback?

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Since these authorization flows are usually done by users through their browser, it is not really clear if you are trying to follow the same flow programmatically. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? It might help others to answer your question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the token from the callback link with getQuery() method of HttpExchange. Please consider this question as solved.